# for loop syntax in shell script

Tags: scripts

I run below script:

```
for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))    
do
    echo "Random number $i: $RANDOM"
done
```

I am getting below Error:

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

why this syntax is not working?

Comment: When I copy-paste this into my terminal, it works as inteded. Do you have something else stored in `i` or have a file named "i" in your WD?

Comment: You are probably running it in `sh` ..the syntax is correct for `bash` ..how are you running it?

Comment: ya ..it is  working fine in terminal but getting  error  in script file

Comment: What command are you using to run the script?

Comment: Does your script have `#! /bin/bash` at the beginning?

Comment: i was using sh command to execute the script so due to that script was not executing but once i use " ./abcd.sh " command,it is working fine..do you have any explination on this...?

Comment: As far as your previous records are concerned, you should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You may be interested in an answer by a user posted on my question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198985/how-to-make-mksh-for-loop-go-from-1-to-n

Answer (score 13):

As heemayl's answer points out, your construction is a bashism. The standard way of doing what you want would be:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  echo "Random number $i: $RANDOM"
done
```

Or, more easily expandably:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
  echo "Random number $i: $RANDOM"
done
```

(See `man seq` for more detail).

Comment: Brace expansion is also a bashism.

Comment: `for i in 1 2 3 4 5` is kind of trolling....use `seq 1 5`..

Comment: @heemayl -- Not trolling, I just had to double-check the seq syntax before I included it

Comment: @heemayl no trolling, some users don't know all the minute details of shell scripting =)

Comment: Not that one can say `seq` is all that standard either. It's not POSIX.

Comment: @Serg i agree..but you need to show the right path too along with showing something that won't be that much of a help in the future :)

Answer (score 6):

Your original script has a `(( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))` construct in `for` loop which is a bashism and hence is not being understood by `dash`.

In Ubuntu `sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`, so when you are running

```
sh ./script.sh
```

you are basically running

```
dash ./script.sh
```

As i mentioned earlier `dash` is not understanding the C-like `for` loop construct, it is showing the error.

To run the script using `bash`, you can:

- Run it as as an argument to `bash` e.g. `bash script.sh` (you don't need to make the script executable)
- Make the script executable and from a `bash` shell run (from the directory containing  the script):

  ```
  ./script.sh
  ```
- The most portable way is to use a shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or preferably `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) as the first line of your script. In this way you can run the script from any shell by `./script.sh`, the script will be interpreted as a `bash` script and hence will be executed accordingly.

Comment: For even greater portability, a bash script can start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Although not 100% of Unix-like systems have `env` in `/usr/bin`, those that don't are rarer than those with `bash` not in `bin`. (`bin` doesn't have `bash` on most systems where `bash` is installed but not part of the base system, e.g., FreeBSD.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes..i forgot to mention `env`..that will be most portable..

Answer (score 5):

Thought I'd contribute to the discussion a little bit.

It's already been mentioned that the syntax used in your script is a bashism and hence isn't portable, even though this is C-like and is well understood by those familiar with java and C. From asking my own [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198985/85039) on unix.stackexchange.com , I've also learned that syntax such as `for i in $(seq 1 5)` generates a set of numbers first and then iterates , which can be wasteful if you have a very large set.

A better way to simulate C-like behavior, which is portable, is to use `while` loop, with a variable that can be incremented. For instance,

```
#!/bin/sh
number=0
while [ "$number" -lt 10 ]
do
        printf "\t%d" "$number"
        number=`expr $number + 1 `
done
```

This works with bash, dash, zsh, ksh, mksh . . . or basically any shell related to bourne shell. In fact, I've a Unix System V book from like 1995, and I've tested their example for bourne shell and it still works. The behaviour is also that of C-like for loop: you have initial condition, testing condition within `while [ . . .]`, and update condition at the end.

[csh and tcsh](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/csh-shell-scripting-loop-example/) have syntax closer to C language, but its not portable to other shells, and they're [not recommended](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) to be used in scripting.

**Addition**:

Concerning portability of $RANDOM, according to [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24RANDOM) on ubuntu wiki, with dash random number generation should rely on using `/dev/urandom`

Comment: This is indeed much more efficient when the loop variable can take on many values. For example, on my system, using `command time -f '%E' dash -c '...'` as the test harness, `for i in $(seq 1 100000000); do test $i -eq 1000 && break; done` took 0:48.37, but `i=1; while [ $i -lt 100000000 ]; do test $i -eq 1000 && break; i=$(expr $i + 1); done` took 0:02.23.